# Maximum weighted segment coverage algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

This is a algorithmic question which thought by me, but myself couldn't think of an easy solution.

The problem is inspired by merging two famous problems: Minimum segment coverage & Knapsack problem, and the description is as followed:

Given `n` segments `[l_i, r_i]`, where all `l_i, r_i in [1,M]`. `n, M` are known.

Each segment has a value `v_i`, what is the maximum total value you can get if you can choose any number of non-overlapping segments? (touching is ok)

---

I have a strong feeling that my thought is over-complicated
but now the solution in my head is use dynamic programming like we solve knapsack.

1. Sort the segments by `r_i` in ascending order
2. Define `DP(i) := maximum value we can get using segment [0,i]`, here the index is the sorted index after step 1
3. `DP(i) = max(DP(j) + v[i], DP(i-1))` where `j is the largest index where r_j <= l_i, which can be found using binary search`

I think this solution is of `O(N lg N)`. Now my problem is:

1. Is this solution correct?
2. Is there any easier, better-performance solution?

Comment: This is called "Weighted Interval Scheduling", google it.

Comment: Wow thanks mate, exactly what I looking for...and indeed it is quite classic. In short seems O(N lg N) is the best I can achieve...

Answer (score 0):

The segment coverage can be represented by a graph that is called [interval graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_graph). Since you don't want to take two overlapping segments, you are looking at finding a Maximum Weighted Independent Set in an interval graph. This problem is NP-hard on general graph, but fortunately it can easily be solved on interval graphs. If you look at the [GraphClasses website](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_234.html) you can see that the problem is solvable in linear time, even for the chordal graphs (it is a larger class than the interval graph), and you have the reference to the [original paper](http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/refs1100.html#ref_1166) that proves it.